# SOAP Create web-server for IIS with BizTalk

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, biztalk

I have to configurate SOAP web-service with BizTalk involving

How it must works
 1. Client has login/pass going to `https://soap.mjr.ru/soap.svc`
 2. Client send `Request` like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:doc="https://docflow.mjr.ru.Request">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <doc:Request>
         <MessageIdentifier>1231</MessageIdentifier>
         <MessageType>3B18</MessageType>
         <MessagePriority>1</MessagePriority>
         <XmlRequest>kuehgiuehriveiveibveifbveifbviebfvieb</XmlRequest>
         <Sender>123456789</Sender>
         <Receiver>123456789</Receiver>
      </doc:Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

3. SOAP server at my side receive request and send back to Client answer about good receipt or error code
4. Server take from inbound message data from `Request` field and put it like XML into folder

What i have done

1. In Visual Studio I Have created new BT project with XSD for `Request` and `Response`
2. I have deployed this project into BTS
3. Within utilite `BizTalk WCF service Publishing Wizard` I have publicate schemas as service into /soap/soap.svc
4. Configurate subsite Application Spool by SQL user for DB connection
5. Create new site in IIS and bind it for `https://soap.mjr.ru`
6. Configurate permission for client user for this folder
7. In BizTalk Server Administrator configurate Receive Port & Receive Location (they have been created automatically). Rewrite address to file from `/soap/soap.svc` to `/soap.svc'
8. Run application in BTS and after i can see the file at `https://soap.mjr.ru/soap.svc?WSDL`

But i can't reach my service with SOAPUI. Here i have 401 error.. and that's all

Please help with correct configuration

listing of web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">

  <configSections>
    <section name="bizTalkSettings" type="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkConfigurationSection, 

Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>

  <bizTalkSettings>
    <mexServiceHostFactory debug="false">
      <receiveLocationMappings>
      </receiveLocationMappings>
    </mexServiceHostFactory>
    <webServiceHostFactory debug="false" />
    <isolatedReceiver disable="false" />
    <btsWsdlExporter disable="false" />
  </bizTalkSettings>

  <appSettings />

  <connectionStrings />

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false">

      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="mscorlib, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Common, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </assemblies>

    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <extensions><behaviorExtensions><add name="btsWsdlExporter" type="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Metadata.BtsWsdlExporterElement, 

Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" /></behaviorExtensions></extensions>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <diagnostics>
      <endToEndTracing activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" propagateActivity="true">
      </endToEndTracing>
    </diagnostics>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration">
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" httpsHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>

      <service name="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkServiceInstance" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration">
       <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://10.8.1.226/soap.svc" />
            <add baseAddress="https://soap.mjr.ru/soap.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>        
        <endpoint name="HttpMexEndpoint" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: A 401 is a security issue. What security is enabled on the IIS web service?  What settings do you have for security in SOAPUI?

Comment: Security allow only windows authoriastion. It's exactly what i need - because client send SOAP mesages within Windows Login

Comment: Your bindings are showing clientCredentialType="Basic" authentication rather than Windows.  Also you have not answered how your SOAPUI is configured with credentials.  The two have to match, otherwise they will not work